# Fixing a duplicate in sources.list - Not sure what to delete

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, sudo

For a while I've been having this issue but I'm not too sure what to modify in /etc/apt/sources.list.

Here is my sources.list file:

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl
#

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty main

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty universe
"/etc/apt/sources.list" 62L, 3357C                            1,1           Top

▽
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl
#

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty main

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty universe
"/etc/apt/sources.list" 62L, 3357C                            1,1           Top

▽
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl
#

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty main

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty universe
"/etc/apt/sources.list" 62L, 3357C                            1,1           Top
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl
#

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty main

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty universe
"/etc/apt/sources.list" 62L, 3357C                            1,1           Top
```

And here is the output when i try to run `sudo apt-get update`. A lot of duplicate sources.list entries.

```
Get:1 http://repo.ajenti.org main InRelease [11.7 kB]
Get:2 http://repo.ajenti.org main/main amd64 Packages [6,755 B]
Get:3 http://repo.ajenti.org main/ubuntu amd64 Packages [4,110 B]
Get:4 http://repo.ajenti.org main/main i386 Packages [6,757 B]
Get:5 http://repo.ajenti.org main/ubuntu i386 Packages [4,110 B]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty InRelease
Get:7 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
Get:8 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [119 kB]
Get:10 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty-updates/main Sources [380 kB]
Get:11 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [162 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [40.3 kB]
Get:13 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [889 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [523 kB]
Get:15 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [372 kB]
Get:16 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [851 kB]
Get:17 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [373 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [135 kB]
Get:19 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [430 kB]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [487 kB]
Get:21 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [197 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [135 kB]
Get:23 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty Release [58.5 kB]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en [287 kB]
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [80.8 kB]
Get:26 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty/main Sources [1,064 kB]
Get:27 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty/universe Sources [6,399 kB]
Get:28 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty/main amd64 Packages [1,350 kB]
Get:29 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages [5,859 kB]
Get:30 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty/main i386 Packages [1,348 kB]
Get:31 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty/universe i386 Packages [5,866 kB]
Get:32 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty/main Translation-en [762 kB]
Get:33 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty/universe Translation-en [4,089 kB]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.ajenti.org main/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.ajenti.org main/main Translation-en
Ign http://repo.ajenti.org main/ubuntu Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.ajenti.org main/ubuntu Translation-en
Fetched 32.4 MB in 24s (1,318 kB/s)
Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian/ main/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.ajenti.org_ng_debian_dists_main_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian/ main/ubuntu amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.ajenti.org_ng_debian_dists_main_ubuntu_binary-amd64_Packages)
Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian/ main/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.ajenti.org_ng_debian_dists_main_main_binary-i386_Packages)
Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian/ main/ubuntu i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.ajenti.org_ng_debian_dists_main_ubuntu_binary-i386_Packages)
You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian/ main/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.ajenti.org_ng_debian_dists_main_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian/ main/ubuntu amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.ajenti.org_ng_debian_dists_main_ubuntu_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian/ main/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.ajenti.org_ng_debian_dists_main_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian/ main/ubuntu i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.ajenti.org_ng_debian_dists_main_ubuntu_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Hope you can help me. I'm definitely not the best at Linux so I was confused on how I should modify the sources.

EDIT:

The commmand grep ajenti /etc/apt/ -R gives me this:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian main main ubuntu
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian main main ubuntu
Binary file /etc/apt/trusted.gpg matches
/etc/apt/sources_backup.list:deb http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian main main ubuntu
/etc/apt/sources_backup.list:deb http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian main main ubuntu
```

Comment: Look at `grep ajenti /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: I entered the command `grep ajenti /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`, however it said "grep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*: No such file or directory"

Comment: strange. then find your whole `/etc` where the ajenti repos are stored. they're not in sources.list what you pasted here.

Comment: Would finding the Ajenti repos have anything to do with the duplicate sources errors during `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: What does this give you?  `grep ajenti /etc/apt/ -R` If nothing then try this  `grep ajenti /etc/ -R`

Comment: Sorry for the late response.

Comment: I just edited the post and added the output of `grep ajenti /etc/apt/ -R`.